# BeagleBoard-Simulink: build-in a simulink block to read an .avi file

Tags: linux, matlab, simulink, beagleboard

I need to compile by simulink inside BB hardware a block that returns an .avi video signal like the 'From a Multimedia File' simulink block.

I tried to compile a simulink model with 'From a Multimedia File' block but building fails since, i think, it can not transfer "block + file" into BB.

How can i make it to out a video file signal as stand-alone application ?

Comment: By mathworks support package i can transfer a simulink model into BB hardware using simulink blocks and BB simulink library. When i tried to transfer a simulink model with 'From Multimedia File' block it failed. I need just a block like 'From Multimedia File' (with an .avi loaded) to transfer into BB. I hope i was clear. Thanks.

Comment: the error is:**stopping the model**

**Could not open library: frommmfile.dll**

Answer (score 1):

Does the BB have any file I/O? Otherwise, it doesn't make sense at all to generate code for the block... The [doc for the DSP block](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/dsp/ref/frommultimediafile.html) says:

> This block supports code generation for the host computer that has
>   file I/O available. You cannot use this block with Real-Time Windows
>   Target™ software because that product does not support file I/O.

It also says that the "generated code for this block relies on prebuilt library files" and recommends using [PackNGo](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/rtw/ref/packngo.html) to make sure all the dependencies are included in the generated code. If you haven't look at the documentation for the block yet, I strongly recommend that you do so.

Also, there is [another block with the same name](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/vision/ref/frommultimediafile.html) from the Computer Vision System Toolbox, which one are you referring to? Again, look at the doc, it has the same comments about requiring prebuilt library files.

I'm not sure whether the code generation will work with the BB target (note that the doc only mentions "host" computer as opposed to target), but the fact remains that the target does require file I/O otherwise it's a pointless exercise.